# TLS in Ingress setup timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

I deployed a basic service in my kubernetes cluster. I handle routing using this Ingress:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: owncloud
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: owncloud
              servicePort: 80
```

I generated a kubernetes secret in default namespace using a generated key and certificate. I named it `example-tls` and add it to the Ingress config under spec:

```
tls:
- secretName: example-tls
  hosts: 
    - example.com
```

When I GET the service using https (`curl -k https://example.com`), it times out:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

It works using http.

What's possibly wrong here?

Here is the `describe` output of the concerned `ingress`:

```
Name:             owncloud
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  example.com
                               owncloud:80 (10.40.0.4:80)
Annotations:
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"owncloud","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"example.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"owncloud","servicePort":80}}]}}]}}

Events:  <none>
```

My Ingress Controller service:

```
$ kubectl describe service traefik-ingress-service -n kube-system

Name:                     traefik-ingress-service
Namespace:                kube-system
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"traefik-ingress-service","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"port...
Selector:                 k8s-app=traefik-ingress-lb
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.100.230.143
Port:                     web  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 web  32001/TCP
Endpoints:                10.46.0.1:80
Port:                     admin  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 admin  30480/TCP
Endpoints:                10.46.0.1:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: Can you share the command output: `kubectl describe ingress owncloud`?

Comment: @mk_sta I edited my post :)

Comment: `Address` should not be empty. Do you have `ingress-controller` installed: `kubectl get svc -o wide| grep ingress-controller` ?

Comment: @mk_sta Yes, I deployed a traefik ingress-controller. I edited my post again. If http route works, It means Ingress system works, isn't it ?

Comment: I don't see any https entry points in traefik ingress service. Try to verify traefik TOML configuration as described [here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/).